# javascript concat() , want to concat 5 different value of string

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have text box with 5 digit numbers given by user,for ex:-if num2=(12345), I want to individual number to be subtract by 10. So the answer for 12345 will be 98765. I have used charAt() to separate the numbers and store in different variables. Then used concat() Which is not working. I am wondering their must be some different efficient approach to get required answer.

```
<input id="num2" type="text" /><br />
<input id ="comRanNum" type="text" /><br />
<input name="" type="button" onclick="check()" value="Click Here" />

function check()
{
var num2=document.getElementById("num2").value;
var temp0=10-num2.charAt(0);
var temp1=10-num2.charAt(1);
var temp2=10-num2.charAt(2);
var temp3=10-num2.charAt(3);
var temp4=10-num2.charAt(4);
var temp5=temp0.concat(temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4);
document.getElementById("comRanNum").value=temp5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem always involves 5 numbers, you could simply use `111110-num2`. E.g., `111110-12345=98765`. To solve the issue for a dynamic amount of numbers, you could make the number of `1`s depend on how long the entered number is.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i will get the answer but this would be the tricy approach.

Answer (score 1):

`temp0` isn’t a string yet, so you can’t call `concat` on it. But if you’re converting it to a string anyways, why bother?

```
var temp5 = '' + temp0 + temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4;
```

Since you specify exactly five digits, though, TVK’s answer is best. Math is always best.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = '12345';
var result = num.split('').map(function (item) {
  return 10 - item;
}).join('');

console.log(result); // 98765
```